# Shifting all elements of int 0 to the back of ArrayList?

Tags: java

I am creating a method that moves all instancese of 0 to the end of the ArrayList, but preserves the original order of the other numbers.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> 
zerosBack(ArrayList<Integer> arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        if(arr.get(i) == 0){
            arr.remove(i);
            arr.add(0);
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
```

The method seems to work with all inputs except for this one: [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

My program outputs: [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0] instead of [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: When you shift things around, the elements after `i` will have their index decremented. Say you have `i = 0` and `[0, 0, 3]`. After your first iteration you have `[0, 3, 0]` but you increment `i` and basically skip the other `0` which is now at index `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best to iterate an ArrayList from the end and move to the front whenever removing elements. This eliminates the indexing error that occurs when you go from the front of the list to the end of the list. For example, the following code should work:

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> zerosBack(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
    for (int i = arr.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (arr.get(i) == 0) {
            arr.remove(i);
            arr.add(0);
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the original size then remove all zero's and add them back in one go using the original size vs the current size

```
public static List<Integer> zerosBack(List<Integer> arr) {
    int count = arr.size();
    arr.removeIf(v -> v == 0);
    if (count != arr.size()) {
        arr.addAll(Collections.nCopies(count - arr.size(), 0));
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more time and space efficient code and the element ordering does not matter.

```
static ArrayList<Integer> zerosBack(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        int firstCounter = 0;
        int lastCounter = arr.size() - 1;
        while (lastCounter > firstCounter) {
            if (0 == arr.get(lastCounter)) {
                lastCounter--;
                continue;
            }
            if (0 != arr.get(firstCounter)) {
                firstCounter++;
                continue;
            }
            arr.set(firstCounter, arr.get(lastCounter));
            arr.set(lastCounter, 0);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```